# is it better to use embedding with attributes in collaborative filtering or content-based approach?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, recommender-system

I have a dataset with different text documents, a set of users who each read a different document, some historical info such as their reading speed, and other attributes related to the texts and users.

I want to predict their speed on a new set of documents. The new documents will not be the ones used in the test before, and different users tend to read different text in a non-repeated way.

Could this be treated as collaborative filtering with speed viewed as ratings? if so how to use the text/doc embedding as input? The user - text id or user - text embedding will barely form a matrix given the unique pairing, though user - text attribute could form a matrix.

Or is it better to treat it as a content-based approach? or still other approaches? What would you advise? Thanks.